# ValueError: Unknown metric function: top_2_accuracy. Please ensure this object is passed to the `custom_objects` argument

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'm working on a CNN classification project, and I've used the top 2 Accuracy (top_k_categorical_accuracy) as the accuracy matrix for training.
the function in the model notebook is:

```
from tensorflow.keras.metrics import top_k_categorical_accuracy

def top_2_accuracy(y_true, y_pred):
    return top_k_categorical_accuracy(y_true, y_pred, k=2)
```

then I used it as

```
model.compile(optimizer = Adam(lr = 4e-3), 
              loss='categorical_crossentropy', 
              metrics=['accuracy', top_2_accuracy])
```

Now I need to load the model to use it in an application
I tried to use this code:

```
model = tf.keras.models.load_model('model.h5')
```

but an error occurred while loading

```
Unknown metric function: top_2_accuracy. Please ensure this object is passed to the `custom_objects` argument. See https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/save_and_serialize#registering_the_custom_object for details.
```

then I've googled and tried this too:

```
model = tf.keras.models.load_model('model.h5', custom_objects={'top_k_categorical_accuracy(y_true, y_pred, k=2)':top_2_accuracy})
```

but it generated another error

```
model = tf.keras.models.load_model('model.h5', custom_objects={'top_k_categorical_accuracy(y_true, y_pred, k=2)':top_2_accuracy})
NameError: name 'top_2_accuracy' is not defined
```

How can I solve this??

Comment: the object name is top_2_accuracy, this is the string you need to pass to custom objects.

Comment: I actually did it as
`model = tf.keras.models.load_model('model.h5', custom_objects={'top_2_accuracy':top_k_categorical_accuracy(y_true, y_pred, k=2)})`

but error 
`NameError: name 'y_true' is not defined`

And I don't know how to define  y_true or y_pred in loading.

Comment: the correct way is 'top_2_accuracy': top_2_accuracy, you need to previously define top_2_accuracy of coursed.